# iOS: What's the best way to display a string that has a portion of it in a different color?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I currently have a UILabel that has a bit of text. What I need to do now is to change the text color of a couple of words in the label. I don't think there's a way to do this with just UILabel and was curious what would be the best way to approach this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Colored substring in UITextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241248/colored-substring-in-uitextfield)

Answer (score 4):

You can put an NSAttributedString in a label. I'll post an example from one of my projects in a sec.

**Edit:** I just realized I removed the code from the project. Anyway, you need this control and everything will be easy:

https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/

It's an UILabel subclass that accepts attributed strings.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only ways to do this are by using Core Text or displaying the text as HTML in a UIWebView.

Core Text is more efficient and clean more strictly Cocoa, but using a UIWebView is a lot less complicated, as HTML is fairly easy. I would say the main issue with using the web view is that you cannot back the background transparent, which I mention because I know this is often needed for text.

Check out Core Text here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Actually you can make it transparent. The problem with webview is that it doesn't show its contents instantly.

Answer (score 0):

You should try TTTAttributedLabel. It's a drop-in replacement for UILabel that works with NSAttributedString and is performant enough for UITableViewCells.

This is *not* a piece from the Three20 library, which is known to be pretty heavy and bloated.